# Align flex items like a grid using only flexbox CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to left align items in a flexbox like so. However i cannot get them to align like in a grid display, ive tried all the flexbox properties but can only get it to work using a grid, but i cannot use a grid here.

[image]

Here is the code i have:

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align:left; 
}
```

I need all text to align left by the red line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is needed to fix the width of each items to align the position.

Try to add `flex-basis` css property to all child styles.
So if the above style is something like `.list-item`, then add this style to all childs like...

```
.list-item > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```